# Tailwind CSS install does not work on M1 Mac

Tags: css, macos, npm, installation, apple-m1

I can't install Tailwind CSS on my MacBook Pro M1, 2020.
Whenever I try to install it with

> npm install tailwindcss@latest

I get :

> npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.5.2',
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' },
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.0.0', npm: '8.10.0' > }
> npm WARN EBADENGINE }
>
> up to date, audited 968 packages in 4s
>
> 69 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
>
> 12 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 7 high, 3 critical)
>
> To address all issues, run:
> npm audit fix
>
> Run `npm audit` for details.

I did run

> npm audit fix

and

> npm audit fix --force

But it still does not work.
It seems to me that Tailwind is not supporting M1 yet. Can I still use it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I only see warnings that are unrelated. The install is successful. What is the issue?

Comment: I was not sure about that because it's said Unsupported Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a WARN, not straight up an error.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' }
```

This looks like the package expects you to use a version of the node between 0.8 and 9.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE current: { node: 'v18.0.0', npm: '8.10.0' > }
```

While this says you are currently using version 18.
That means that some of the functionalities of the package may not work as intended, but it should still be fine.